# How to find and understand the autograd source code in PyTorch

Tags: python, backpropagation, pytorch, autograd

I have a good understanding of the autograd algorithm, and I think I should learn about the source code in PyTorch. However, when I see the project on GitHub, I am confused by the structure, cuz so many files include autograd. So which part is the most important core code of autograd?

Comment: I've made an article about the code base here: http://blog.christianperone.com/2018/03/pytorch-internal-architecture-tour/ if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to understand the autograd [variable](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/autograd/variable.py) is probably the first thing, what you can do. From my understanding is autograd only a naming for the modules, which containing classes with enhancement of gradients and backward functions.
2. Be aware a lot of the algorithm, e.g. back-prop through the graph, is hidden in compiled code.
3. If you look into the [__init__.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/autograd/__init__.py), you can get a glimpse about all important functions (backward & grad)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make associations between your understanding of autograd and the PyTorch datastructures involved by making a simple graph and printing/visualizing the structure as below:

- [Print Autograd Graph](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/print-autograd-graph/692)
- [Resnet example viz](https://github.com/szagoruyko/functional-zoo/blob/master/resnet-18-export.ipynb) (jupyter notebook)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reading the PyTorch code is doable, but you may be overwhelmed with details. To get a basic idea of autograd, you may want to refer to some simple autograd implementations, such as https://evcu.github.io/ml/autograd/ and https://medium.com/@ralphmao95/simple-autograd-implementation-understand-automatic-differentiation-hand-by-hand-9e86f6d703ab